# Combining two model attributes when printing with "firstof" template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to print two model attributes **if they both exist**, how do I do this in django?

in pseudocode {% firstof user.first_name + user.last_name ... %}

is there an easy way to do this? i.e. what I should have to **replace the plus sign**

Thanks.

Comment: Would make sense to put a `display_name` on your model that returns a display name or `''`... and use that

Comment: Why not use user.get_full_name()